# How to get the id of element when right clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I like to know how to get the id of li when i right click over this li using javascript or jquery.

```
<ul>
    <li id="liid" class="collapsable">
        <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
        </div>
        <span class="folder">Group1.2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the right click  function.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
    // code to get the id of current li
});
```

Can any one help me please.

Comment: @srvikram13 guess again..

Comment: My Bad! `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: do you need this functionallity for other a elements also ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.on('contextmenu', 'li')`

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').on('contextmenu', 'li', function(e) { //Get li under ul and invoke on contextmenu
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent defaults
        alert(this.id); //alert the id
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DLWH/)

Comment: this is too easy. I dont think he wants to bind it only to LI. but to X element ( maybe im wrong about this)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I just posted what he questioned for *I like to know how to get the id of li when i right click over this li*

Comment: Yes I agree +1. But I thought to myself , how can I do this with general elements. interesting question.

Comment: Although probably a small issue, this solution binds an event to all `<ul>` elements; just fyi :)

Comment: @Jack I expect something from the OP to use like `ul#blah` or `ul.blah` or atleast `div.class ul` :D

Comment: i have one more doubt that if i have a child to one li then it will this code will hit more than than one time.. ie   ` <ul><li class="collapsable"><div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea"></div><span class="folder">Group1.2</span><ul><li class="last">
<div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="file">Form1.1</span> 
                                    </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>' here is my code

Comment: @Aswathy If you have nested `li` than u need to use `ul.class_name > li`

Answer (score 3):

This uses event delegation on `document` and only fires if an `li` is clicked.

```
$(document)
    .on('contextmenu', 'li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.id);
    });
```

Compared to adding a handler on `$('ul')` or `$('li')`, this will only bind a single handler.

Comment: @Mr.Alien The `return false` should accomplish the same, but sure, edited :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(function() {
    $('li').on("contextmenu", function (e) {
        alert(this.id);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xyhj2/1/)

Comment: This binds an event handler to all `<li>` elements, so may not be an optimal solution.

Comment: @Jack I agree, but OP just wants to know how to get the id of li tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this..

If you want open also Context Menu on right click then use below code:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').on('contextmenu', function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

and without Context Menu then use below code:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Happy New year...